# How to make an ellipse move up and down on processing

Tags: processing

I want to make an ellipse move up and down 
So, can you tell me how to make an ellipse move up and down

Comment: like this, float x =0;
int dir =1;
void setup()
{
  size(500,300);
  background(50);

 }
void draw()
{
  background(50);
 
  ellipse(x+30, 30,30,30);
  x = x+(3*dir);
  
    if ((x> width-30) ||(x < 0))
  {
    dir=dir*-1;
  }
  else
  {
    ;
  }
 }

Comment: Which programming language are you using? Java? C? How the code you wrote does not act as you expected?

Comment: I am using Java processing

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:** Store the **state** of your scene in some variables. For you, this might just by a `circleY` variable.

```
float circleY = 50;
```

**Step 2:** Use that variable to draw your scene.

```
ellipse(50, circleY, 10, 10);
```

**Step 3:** Modify that variable over time to change the scene.

```
circleY++;
```

**Step 4:** Add checks to make sure your variables don't go outside the range.

```
if(circleY > height){
  circleY = 0;
}
```

Putting it all together, it looks like this:

```
float circleY = 50;

void draw() {
  background(0);
  ellipse(50, circleY, 10, 10); 
  circleY++;
  if (circleY > height) {
    circleY = 0;
  }
}
```

[image: falling circle]

Of course, this is just an example. You'd have to add extra logic for switching direction instead of teleporting back to the top of the screen. You might use a `directionY` variable that you switch when the circle hits the top or bottom of the screen.

But the basics are the same: use variables to store your state, change those variables over time, and draw your scene using those variables.

I suggest you **try something** and post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in a new question if you get stuck. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the sin or cosine functions to oscillate the circle up and down!

```
float angle = 0;

public void draw() {
    if (angle > 359) {
        angle = 0;
    }
    ellipse(0, sin(radians(angle)) * height, 20, 20);
    angle++;
}
```

Comment: If you want to get rid of that `angle` variable, you could also use `frameRate % 360` instead.

Comment: That would only work if your frameRate is 360, which it shouldn't be.  You only get the full up and down oscillations from the full 360 degree angle loop with sin or cos.

Comment: Also the solution in your answer only animates the circle going down, not up and down as the asker specified.  Using directional variables is too complicated for this purpose.

Comment: Whoops, that's a type: should be **`frameCount%360` instead, not `frameRate`. Your program becomes one line of code: `ellipse(0, sin(radians(frameCount%360)) * height, 20, 20);`

Comment: The OP didn't really provide enough information to decide what is too complicated, but I think a directional variable is a little easier to understand than using the `sin()` function anyway. To each their own. I think both of our answers are valid. But I purposely left out the circle going back up because I wanted to focus on the basics of setting up an animation first.

Comment: oh yes frameCount would work, that's a nice solution!  And yeah I see where you were coming from.